# 404 for OPTIONS method in Google AppEngine with Java and Angular.js

Tags: java, angularjs, google-app-engine, http-options-method

I am using Angular.js with AppEngine on Java.
For every HTTP request, Angular.js issues an OPTIONS request before actual request, which returns an HTTP 404 error for me.
Can anybody please tell me why?

In AppEngine how to enable the configuration for OPTIONS method?

**edit:** I created a filter to handle OPTIONS request. Now I add the **Allow** header with **GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD** as value and respond with status code **200**. But still it shows 404.

Comment: it depends on your server side framework. which do you use? and it's not simply "enable", you have to write an handler for such request. could be a plain servlet though

Comment: I am using Google App Engine with Google Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: Now, I am responding 200 OK with headers set as Allow:GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD. still it shows 404

Comment: please show your code. also, servlets better suits this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working.
I wrote the code like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=3600");
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "www.myapp.com");
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    if (req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) { 
        resp.flushBuffer();
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, resp);
    }
}
```

I just wrote the resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); before.
After writing the whole headers, it started working.

Comment: `resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")` doesn't change server behavior for 404. and you don't need to put CORS headers for anything except OPTION. also '*' origin is insecure

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will change it.

Comment: Thank you, this saved us loads of time !